# Enforcing more logarithmic axis ticks under free scales in facet_wrap() of ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Apologies for not providing my data. It is too big, and with mock data, i wasnt able to reproduce the problem.

If you look at this:
[image]

You realize that some facets have no or only one x-tick. I want to enforce at least 2 ticks per facets, even though it is logarithmically scaled. Is it possible?

The graph was produced from this code:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Frequency, y = Treatment)) +
  facet_wrap(~ SG, scale = "free_x") +
  geom_point(aes(col = factor(Treatment)), shape = "|") +
  scale_color_manual(values = somecols, guide=FALSE) +
  scale_x_log10()
```